# Hide columns based on a cell value google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I just start learning about google script a few days ago and I'm facing one problem that I can't solve. In my google sheet I want to hide columns C-K if cell B2=FALSE and show columns C-K if cell B2=TRUE. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Add a checkbox to Cell B2 and use this simple onEdit function.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet234' && e.range.columnStart==2 && e.range.rowStart==2) {
    e.source.toast(e.value);
    if(e.value=="TRUE") {
      sh.hideColumns(3,9);
    }else{
      sh.showColumns(3,9);
    }
  }  
}
```

Animation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!

Now how can i do for multiples checkbox, to hide diferent columns?

1. if B2= FALSE, hide columns C-K
2. if L2= FALSE, hide columns M-U
3. if V2= false, hide columns W-AE
4. if AF2= FALSE, hide columns AG-AO
5. if AP2= FALSE, hide columns AQ-AY
6. if AZ2= false, hide columns BA-BI
7. if BJ2= FALSE, hide columns BK-BS
8. if BT2= FALSE, hide columns BU-CC
9. if CD2= false, hide columns CE-CM
10. if CN2= FALSE, hide columns CO-CW
11. if CX2= FALSE, hide columns CY-DG
12. if DH2= false, hide columns DI-DQ

Comment: I might consider building a little control panel with a column of check boxes next to a column that tells you what columns to operate on